# How to get sum of values in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have got Table:

```
id        name      amount
--------------------------
1         abc       1
2         abc       2
3         abc       -3
4         def       4
```

I want to get sum of every amounts of name==abc, i mean 1+2+(-3) = 0;

How to do this in MySql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE name = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about mySQL, but "standard" SQL would be:

```
select sum(amount) from yourTableName where name='abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM table WHERE name = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) from Table GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM tableName
WHERE name='abc'
```